# How to pass a parameter to a custom attribute ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to create a custom attribute that will check if a user has access to a resource before they enter the API route. The attribute, will ideally look something like this on the route.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetOrders")]
[SecurityFunctionFilter("GETORDERS")]   // <-- desired attribute
public IActionResult GetOrders()
{
    ActionResult response;
    try
    {
        response = Ok();
    }
    catch
    {
        response = new StatusCodeResult(500);
    }
    return response;
}
```

In order to implement this, I tried to create a filter extending Attribute and implementing the IAuthorizationFilter Interface like this below. The Attribute on the controller route will pass a string security function which will set in the SecurityFunctionFilter constructor. This will be checked, and if receives false, will return 404 in the API.

```
public class SecurityFunctionFilter : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string _securityFunction;

    public SecurityFunctionFilter(string securityFunction)
    {
        _securityFunction=securityFunction;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
            // Not yet implemented, will check the users username against security function and return bool
        if (_securityFunction == "GETORDERS")
        {
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(403);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside my program.cs, I did the following:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.

    builder.Services.AddControllers();

    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("corsapp", builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
    }));

    builder.Services.AddScoped<SecurityFunctionFilter>();


    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
        app.UseCors("corsapp");
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthorization();


    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
}
```

When attempting to run, an error was thrown at builder.Build(). This is the error:

```
Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: testing_proj_api.Filters.SecurityFunctionFilter Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: testing_proj_api.Filters.SecurityFunctionFilter': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'testing_proj_api.Filters.SecurityFunctionFilter'.)
```

SOLUTION:

All I needed to do was remove the SecurityFunctionFilter from the services register in program.cs.

Comment: If you don't register `SecurityFunctionFilter ` service  still, does that encounter the exception? and is there anything else you haven't shared with us?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron this seems to have done it...thank you very much for your help.  All I needed to do was remove it from the services and that fixed it.

Comment: Right you are, in my test I have't registered the service which actually don't need in this scenario, because it would only need to invocke while the controller will hit, and its working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> testing_proj_api.Filters.SecurityFunctionFilter Lifetime: Scoped
> ImplementationType: testing_proj_api.Filters.SecurityFunctionFilter':
> Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to
> activate 'testing_proj_api.Filters.SecurityFunctionFilter'.)

Well, according to my test and based on your errors and the description it seems that you don't need to register `SecurityFunctionFilter` in the DI Container. Because it would only need to invoke when the controller is hit thus we don't need to register in the DI Container. In addition, the way you have registered the `AddScoped` DI is also incorrect.

Here I have reproduced your issue and got rid of the following service and it's working as expected:

No need for this service:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<SecurityFunctionFilter>();
```

Another important point is that, the error has been thrown not because of your action filter but the incorrect invocation of `AddScoped` service. The right way to register `AddScoped` service is:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
```

**Note:** AddScoped service also requires its Interface in order to register.

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#register-groups-of-services-with-extension-methods) for more details.